# Why can't I use $nin, $exists, etc. inside a Mongo pipeline match?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I've looked high and low for this answer and nothing has worked. I have a pipeline query with a match term like this:

```
$match: {
  $expr: {
    $and: [
      ....
    ]
  }
}
```

Inside the $and I have all sorts of conditions using $eq, $in, $ne, $gt, $lt, etc.

However try as I may I can't get it to recognize $nin or $exists. I'm trying to add a term where I search for a key not existing, eg:

```
{ $exists: [ '$key', 0 ] }
```

I keep getting

> MongoError: Unrecognized expression '$exists'

and

> MongoError: Unrecognized expression '$nin'

Can anyone help??

Comment: You can only use **aggregation** operators inside the `$expr` and the `$nin` and `$exists` are **query** operators not aggregation ones. Use the above conditions outside the `$expr`

Comment: Yes!!! Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only use `aggregation` operators inside the [**`$expr`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) and the [**`$nin`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/) and [**`$exists`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) are query operators not `aggregation` ones. Use the above conditions outside the [**`$expr`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) expression.

Something like

```
{ "$match": {
  "key": { "$exists": true },
  "$expr": {
    "$and": [
      {...}, {...}
    ]
  }
}}
```